# Hosting API and Client on same subdomain : Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I have a web application named `foobar`. Inside this `foobar` folder, I have two folders:

1. `client`
2. `server`

The server contains my api and is written using Slim (PHP). I have a file in `server/public/index.php` that will handle it.

The client contains my react code. Inside it, there is a `build` folder that has the `react's` build files; a `index.html` file.

This application will be hosted on a subdomain, namely: `foo.bar.com`

On my SERVER MACHINE, I am using Apache's VirtualHost to configure my server and client.

This is what I want:

1. Any request coming to `foo.bar.com/` should go to `client/build/index.html` (CLIENT REACT WEBSITE).
2. Any request coming to `foo.bar.com/api/*` should go to `server/public/index.php`

Here's what I have got so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foo.bar.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/deployment_foobar

    <Directory /var/www/deployment_foobar/server>
        RewriteRule /api/(.*) /public/index.php
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/deployment_foobar/client>
        RewriteRule / /build
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, RewriteRule still applies from the DocumentRoot. Perhaps RewriteBase will help you here?

Comment: So you mean I'll have to manipulate the base when the request is for `api/*`?

Comment: I would think so, but I could very well be mistaken

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni Are index.php and index.html only two files being served or are there more files in their folders?

Comment: @DusanBajic For server, `index.php` is the only file. 

For client, there is one`.js` and one `.css` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foo.bar.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/deployment_foobar

    RewriteRule ^/api/ /server/public/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/build
    RewriteRule ^ /client/build%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

</VirtualHost>
```